# How do I disable "Update Apple ID Settings" notification?

Tags: apple-id, notifications

[image: Image of notification stating "Update Apple ID Settings"]

I get this notification once a day. I have tried whatever stupid song and dance some deranged product manager thinks is appropriate, and the notification always returns after a day. How do I revoke notification permission for the process that is asserting this notification? (or otherwise disable the process, automatically dismiss the notification, hide the notification, etc. I don't ever want to see this notification, I do not care, and I am tired of being disrupted.) I would also be interested in knowing the package name of the package responsible for the notification, and details governing the database which notification manager uses to manage notification state (e.g. is it in a sqlite db? how do I interact with it programmatically?)

Answers which are off-topic:

- How to disable the notification center (No, I need calendar reminders to work.)
- How to sign in to fix or do things to the Apple ID to fix it. (No, I have tried these things, and the notification always returns.)

Comment: In general you can't suppress System notifications, you'll need to satisfy the underlying request. If this is Big Sur, we had a similar issue, which I think we eventually solved by signing out then back into everything, iCloud, App Store etc

Comment: I don't believe you. Obviously something controls the notification center behavior, and these notifications are plumbed through the notification center (turning off the NC disables these notifications,) so by controlling the notification center it may be possible to squelch these notifications.

Comment: I honestly don't know the mechanism, but if you just look at it logically, something which doesn't have a pref in there doesn't have a switch. That it's plumbed through there doesn't mean it's controlled from there. It's coincidence that the new [personal opinion redacted] notification centre missed a trick allowing you to shut them off globally, rather than preserving them as used to happen.

Comment: @InfestedTaco https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452757/apple-id-on-system-settings-asking-for-the-password-for-the-apple-id-null/453863

Comment: @Ezekiel I should have been more specific, I don't have nor want an Apple ID and will never be signing in to any cloud services.

Comment: @InfestedTaco Yes I know, that issue I linked to concerns Ventura incorrectly asking for passwords when it shouldn't and my answer confirms that 13.2 fixes it

Comment: @InfestedTaco I had this problem and didn't have an Apple ID; it's either been fixed (after a wait) by updating to 13.2, or I found a manual fix. Not sure which! https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454788/70448