# Apple ID on System Settings asking for «the password for the Apple ID "(null)"» for ever, how to solve?

Tags: icloud, apple-id, accounts

I get the warning from System Settings saying I should *Update Apple ID Settings*
I login with my Apple ID and correct password (it works on the apple id site and app store) but it just goes back to asking me to *Update Apple ID Settings* ad infinitum.

Something that seems odd is the login message:
*set up iCloud enter the password for the Apple ID "(null)"*
What is that null? is something failing here?

The device IS added to this Apple ID.

[image]

Comment: Can you login to iCloud on the web https://www.icloud.com/ icloud login is not the same as AppStore/Music login

Comment: I've been having this same issue, it was on macOS 11 and I just upgraded to 13 and it's still there, just even more persistent now. What confuses me even more is that It takes my current account username and password but the error stays, and if I mistype anything it gives me a bad credentials error. So weird.

Comment: @mix3d Yeah, I wonder how Apple nails most of UX like a boss but then it has these weird and annoying usability bloopers that stay for too long without getting fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue should be resolved with macOS Ventura 13.2

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Do you have a link to a release note or errata that references this?  This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: The release notes do not mention all bug fixes, but I've been told confidently it has been addressed in 13.2. If people have updated and it is still happening feel free to downvote/let me know and I'll delete this.

Comment: I have only just signed up so don't have the reputation currently to reply to Ezekiel, but I have just updated to 13.2 and the issue definitely remains.

Comment: @RobSandall So you're on 13.2 and not signed in, but receiving alerts to enter your password?

Comment: Updating to 13.2 did not *immediately* fix my problem. Either the fix requires waiting a little while, or I found a manual fix.  I'm not sure which! https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454788/70448

Comment: Hmm, interesting...perhaps they fixed the cause of the issue but people who had already experienced it might need to reset a little more stuff

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with a client using an earlier operating system. We had to resort to Apple Tech Support on a telephone call.

Now that you've updated to the most recent operating system, I suggest signing out of your Apple ID and then signing in again. To do this, in System Settings tap your name. Scroll to the bottom of the pane and click Sign Out.

Note: if you use iCloud Drive for storage, or Mail, Contacts, Calendars, etc. you will be asked what you want to do with that data before logging out. Here's more info.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/sign-apple-settings-mac-mh36825/13.0/mac/13.0

If that doesn't clear the error, I would suggest calling Apple Support. They will connect you with the team that specializes in Apple ID. The geniuses at the stores are not allowed to do Apple ID stuff, so I'd start with a call.

Comment: While this error does sometimes appear in the past, something in Ventura is triggering this more. I don't see this error on my machine personally but I hear from many people who do and I'm looking for a process that can reliably clear the error.

I do suspect that signing out and back in would resolve the issue, but I've also seen some people who aren't even signed in at all getting this message in Ventura specifically.

Comment: I found that by logging out, then logging back in made it go away, so this answer is good in my book.