# How to fix "Update Apple ID Settings" bug, when I don't have an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, notifications, keychain

My macbook has been upgraded to macOS 13.2 today.

This has not cleared my problem.  I still have a notification from System Settings, that wants me to "Update Apple ID Settings".

I have never created an Apple ID.  Nobody has logged into an Apple ID on this macbook.  I don't particularly want to create one.

I read [How to fix the “Update Apple ID Settings” bug in MacOS Catalina](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/fix-update-apple-id-settings-bug-macos-catailna/) [digitaltrends.com].  I can't follow the "simple" logout & login steps because I don't have an Apple ID.  I tried the "complex" method of removing the random UUID folder in `~/Library/Keychains`, but it did not work.

In desperation, I tried the "wrong" method from [Mac keeps saying update Apple ID settings](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250711886) [discussions.apple.com].

That is, I saw someone gave confusing instructions, and one or two people cleared `/Library/Keychains/apsd.keychain`, and thought that worked.  I tried this, but it did not work.  (I don't know why it would work, and it could be dangerous.  Please don't try this method unless you really know what you're doing).

### Motivation

I do not want this permanent red dot on System Settings, showing an unresolved issue.  I want a red dot on System settings when there is a security update, so that I do not miss it.  When there is not a security update, or another important issue, I do not want a red dot on System Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I opened Keychain Access. (I searched for it).

In Local Items, I deleted *all* the entries for `com.apple.cloudd.deviceidentifier.Production`, plus `iCloud Keychain Account Meta-data`.

After logging out and back in, I think the red dot remained.  But, when I went to System Settings, the entry for "Update Apple ID Settings", on the left below "sign in with your apple ID", had gone.  Then I noticed the red dot was gone.

It's possible this was a coincidence, and macOS had just fixed the problem itself, a few minutes after the upgrade to 13.2.  There was a notification about "optimizing" my computer, and that it would be slower until it had finished.  See also: ["I've been told confidently it has been addressed in 13.2"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452757/apple-id-on-system-settings-asking-for-the-password-for-the-apple-id-null#comment659780_453863).